# Multiple entries for one object with different cover images

Tags: images

I'm setting up a website for a multilingual publishing company. Since all their books are available in different languages, there are different cover images for each language combination. So e.g. German-English has a different cover image than German-French etc.

So far, I've got the books set up as the product post types by wooCommerce since the books will be available in a online store. Languages are available to select as taxonomies. The Cover-image part is trickier, since I don't want to add multiple images to a book and then display all of them but only display whichever cover-image is correct for the current selection.
I thought about setting up a custom post type for cover-images, too. But I'm not sure if that's the correct approach?
Any suggestions?

Comment: I think I would create an image upload field for each Language term, then display the appropriate image based on what language term the post is associated with. Term meta has been available since WP version 4.4.

Comment: thanks @DaveRomsey Do you have an idea how I could assign the language to that post type? Something like: I want a checkbox for each language and if it's selected you get the chance to upload the cover image for that language and simultaneously, the book get's assigned to the category/taxonomy/tag of that language. I would like to have that function to be able to filter the books by language afterwards..